# using awk and sed find using lines in a file based on a field value from awk

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I use a postfix relay to send our mail from our email servers.
I want to first get the serial number value of the emails from certain users then using that value get the email address they are sending to.  Below are examples of the from and to log entries.  I would think you have to use a combination of awk and sed.

The sender line

```
Nov  4 14:29:53 server postfix/qmgr[2089]: 42UE78JD7JE: from=<sender@domain.som>, size=1182, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```

The reciever line

```
Nov  4 14:29:54 server postfix/smtp[10544]: 42UE78JD7JE: to=<user@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.22.27]:25, delay=1, delays=0.02/0.
```

in the above example I want to extract 42UE78JD7JE from the first line and then find it in the second line.  I am thinking you would use awk to get the serial number value in the line with 'sender@domain.com' then use that value to search for lines with that value and 'to='.

Comment: in reciver file there is space b/w server posix ??

Comment: This is one file.  I want to do this to the maillog on a linux server.  The first line gives me the serial number of the email with the sender of the email. I want to put that serial number in a variable and then use the variable to search for that serial number and the search phrase "to=<" which would give me the recipient of the email.

Comment: i got ur question,  I am asking is there any space between server and posix in both file???? reciver and sender??

Comment: oh sorry I misunderstood.  Yes that was a finger check. I corrected the error.

Comment: What do you want to do with the data here? What is your desired goal/output?

Comment: you want to print both sender and reciver email address with same serial number

Comment: My goal is to extract the recipients from the maillog but to do that I must match the sender domain with the recipient and the serial number on the sender line would be the search along with the  sed snippet 'to=<\(.*\)>, relay'.

Comment: edit your post and show us your expected output

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '
    $7 ~ /^from=/ {from[$6]=$7} 
    $7 ~ /^to=/   {to[$6]=$7} 
    END {for (key in from) if (key in to) print from[key], to[key]}
' file
```

```
from=<sender@domain.som>, to=<user@gmail.com>,
```

Answer (score 0):

using awk

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$6]=$6;b[$6]=$7}NR>FNR{if($6 in a){print substr($7,0,length($7)),substr(b[$6],0,length(b[$6]));}}' sender_file reciver_file
```

output:

```
to=<user@gmail.com> from=<sender@domain.som>
```

THis is what i think you want. if you give us the expected output, it can be improved

Comment: This is good. I will first look at your code because I do have some awk experience and refine it.  In the end I just want the to and from. I don't need the serial number of the email.  awesome coding though.